# svn backup from googlecode

Tags: svn, backup, google-code

I currently host my project on googlecode svn, however I would like to have a copy of it hosted on another svn server (also online), can anyone suggest the best way to keep this backed up and up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Dump and sync will work, but it's probably easiest to use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.html) instead, assuming you're using the copy server as a read-only backup and not intending to commit to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/
2. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5

Though I'd recommend you [switching to git](http://www.jonmaddox.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/), it is easy.